# can I mutate a selector value?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I have an app using NGRX.

I have a question, I know the store is a readonly place where you can't mutate object directly.
But when I use a selector

Like if I have the following ngrx selector

```
export const getSelectedMission = (state: State): Readonly<IMission> => state.selectedMission;
export const selectedMission: MemoizedSelector<object, Readonly<string>> = createSelector(
  selectMissionState,
  getSelectedMissionId
);
```

If in my app I do this

```
this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedMission)).subscribe((mission) => mission.name = "123")
```

Is this a valid operation ? or it should be avoided ?

If I want to select portion in the store, and be able to edit those value (to dispatch action again in the store), what would be the best way ? Should I make all my selector return a copy of the object/array ?

EDIT :

It's fine to do so, but only if you do a copy of the object.

What if I do like this in the component :

```
this.selectedMission$ = this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedMission))
```

Then in the template I pass this value to a child

```
<app-child [mission]="selectedMission$ | async"></app-child>
```

And in the child I so at some point

```
mission.name = "123"
```

This would edit the direct reference of the value in the store right? but the child component shouldn't care about making copy of the object before mutating it.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine to give back a different result. But you should clone the object like this:

```
this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedRouteId)).subscribe((mission) => ({...mission, name: "123"}))
```

EDIT after EDIT

The whole idea of a store is that if you change a value of an object from the store that it should be via the store. So if your component, for whatever reason, wants do mutations directly on a object from the store, then the component should clone the object.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to mutate a value from the store you need to spread it, but you need to be very careful here because if the value is a deep object you need to take care about its nested values too.

```js
this.selectedMission$ = this.store$.pipe(
  select(MissionsStoreSelectors.selectedMission),

  // now we do a deep clone and can pass it anywhere.
  map(value => JSON.stringify(JSON.encode(value))),
);
```

---

The right way would be to use `outputs` and `actions` like that.

```html
<app-child [mission]="selectedMission$ | async" (update)="update($event)"></app-child>
```

the `app-child` should emit at some point

```js
this.update.emit({
  ...this.mission,
  name: '123',
});
```

and in the parent component you can dispatch the action.

```js
update(mission): void {
  this.store.dispatch(new UpdateMission(mission));
}
```

In this case you don't need map with JSON magic.